# Displaying date/time field inside renderForm PrestaShop

Tags: php, sql, prestashop, categories

I've added an extra date field inside my categories lang table. All data is saving correctly however when trying to display the data inside renderForm I get no value. If I change the type to "text" the value displays just fine.

Any help is appreciated as I've searched far and beyond now without an answer. I've also tried editing the field type inside the database table.

This is my renderForm method and the field I'm having trouble with:

```
public function renderForm() {
    $this->fields_form_override = array(
        array(
            'type' => 'datetime',
            'label' => $this->l('Startdato'),
            'name' => 'cat_start_date',
            'lang' => true,
            'autoload_rte' => true,
            'hint' => 'Fx 14. september'
        ),
```

This is my Category class overrides:

```
public $cat_start_date;
public $cat_end_date;
public $cat_order_due_date;
public $cat_location;
public $cat_special_msg;

public function __construct($id_category = null, $id_lang = null, $id_shop = null) {
    self::$definition['fields']['cat_start_date'] = array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isDate');
    self::$definition['fields']['cat_end_date'] = array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isDate');
    self::$definition['fields']['cat_order_due_date'] = array('type' => self::TYPE_DATE, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isDate');
    self::$definition['fields']['cat_location'] = array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'lang' => true);
    self::$definition['fields']['cat_special_msg'] = array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING, 'lang' => true);
    parent::__construct($id_category, $id_lang, $id_shop);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `datetime` field must be:

```
lang => false
```

Comment: Thanks! However when I try to save the category, I get an error saying: An error has occured trying to update object category ()

Comment: Maybe you need to update your Category class (and database) with your new field ..? (if you want to add a new field..)

Comment: I already have, the data saves just fine, I just have a problem displaying the date whenever I go to update the category again, like the field itself doesn't know it's of datetime type.